# UICollectionView setScrollEnabled:YES not working

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView which is longer in width than the screen width and so I would like to enable scroll so the user can see it. Unfortunately, the call to setScrollEnabled:YES does not seem to do anything.

```
// CODE TO SET UP

UICollectionView *tabLayerCollectionView;
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout;

// Dont want any space between cells
flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0; // Scrolling works if we have a space inbetween cells, but spaces are not desired.
flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0;

tabLayerCollectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] 
initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, widthOfTabLayer, noteHeight) 
collectionViewLayout:flowLayout];

// HERE - scrolling not working
[flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
[tabLayerCollectionView setScrollEnabled:YES];

[tabLayerCollectionView setDataSource:self];
[tabLayerCollectionView setDelegate:self]; // See below for completness

[tabLayerCollectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:myIdentifier];
[tabLayerCollectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

//NSLog(@"DrumKitViewController tabList count:%i",(int)tabList.count);
[self.view addSubview:tabLayerCollectionView];
[tabLayerCollectionView reloadData];

// TAB LAYER INHERITED METHODS For Completeness

    // Called once
    - (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    NSLog(@"numberOfItemsInSection called Tablist count:%i",(int)tabList.count);

    return tabList.count;
}

// The cell that is returned must be retrieved from a call to dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:
// Called for each indexPath row (after all layout called
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //NSLog(@"collectionView collectionView called index section:%i row:%i",(int)indexPath.section,(int)indexPath.row);

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:myIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSMutableArray *clickList = [tabList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // Background (Not at start or end)
    UIImageView *backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, noteWidth, noteHeight)];
    [backgroundImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_middle.png"]];
    [cell setBackgroundView:backgroundImageView];

    for (NSString *drumTabItem in clickList){

        //NSLog(@"clickList.count:%i drumTabItem:%@",(int)clickList.count,drumTabItem);

        // Get drumTabItem and add to itemImageView
        UIImageView *tabItemImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, noteWidth, noteHeight)];
        tabItemImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:drumTabItem];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:tabItemImageView];

    }

    return cell;
}



// Called for each indexPath row
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if (indexPath.row==0){
       // This has the timing, so make bigger
        widthOfTimeComponent = noteWidth*2;
        return CGSizeMake(noteWidth*2, noteHeight); // Gives more white space
    }
    else {
        NSMutableArray *clickList = [tabList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        for (NSString *item in clickList){

            if ([item isEqualToString:@"bg_middle.png"]){
                //NSLog(@"EMPTY found at indexRow:%i noOfRows:",(int)indexPath.row);

                if (countNonEmptyItems > 32.0){
                    //widthOfTabLayer = widthOfTabLayer + (noteWidth/6);
                    return CGSizeMake(noteWidth/6, noteHeight); // Needs to be shorter
                }
                else if (countNonEmptyItems > 24.0){
                    //widthOfTabLayer = widthOfTabLayer + (noteWidth/4);
                    return CGSizeMake(noteWidth/4, noteHeight); // Needs to be shorter
                }
                else if(countNonEmptyItems > 15.0){
                    //widthOfTabLayer = widthOfTabLayer + (noteWidth/3);
                    return CGSizeMake(noteWidth/3, noteHeight); // Needs to be wider
                }
                else if(countNonEmptyItems > 10.0){
                    //widthOfTabLayer = widthOfTabLayer + (noteWidth/2);
                    return CGSizeMake(noteWidth/2, noteHeight); // Needs to be wider
                }
                else{

                    return CGSizeMake(noteWidth, noteHeight); // 30x165 (
                }
            }
            else{
                return CGSizeMake(noteWidth, noteHeight); // 30x165
            }
        }
    }
    // Shouldn't get here
    return CGSizeMake(noteWidth, noteHeight); // 30x165
}
```

I was under the assumption that setScrollEnabled:YES would enable the scrolling. Any reason as to why it is not working?

Comment: setScrollEnabled to YES would enable scrolling.
 for scrolling horizontally. 
[collectionView setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal]

Answer (score 1):

Scrolling will only work on a UICollectionView (or any other scrollView) if the Content Size is larger than the View Size.

When you init the frame of your collection view, you're setting the size to widthOfTabLayer.  My hunch is that this is actually your content size. So set the width of your collection view to the width of your parent view or screen (we'll call it screenWidth), and set the content size of the collection view to widthOfTabLayer.

```
tabLayerCollectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] 
initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, screenWidth, noteHeight) 
collectionViewLayout:flowLayout];

[flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
flowLayout.contentSize = widthOfTabLayer
```